# Django use two databases for seamless updates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a database (PostgreSQL), which I need to update from time to time (every 6 hours). I don't want partial updates to appear on the output, so my idea is:

We use two databases, let them be named `prod` and `update`. `prod` is all the time on duty, while `update` is being updated every 6 hours and then it should pass changes (or change places) to (with) `prod`.

How can I implement such behaviour in Django? I know, that there are migrations and db_to_write, db_to_read variants, but they stay not clear to me from the tutorial.

Comment: To prevent partial updates you could use transactions as well :)
Writing a custom database backend should do the trick as well.
And there's even the option of just using master/slave replication in Postgres

Comment: Doing master/slave replication in Postgres would be the way to go. This is a common problem that databases have solved well. Trying to write your own back end or solve it in Python seems like it would be very easy to get wrong.