# REST/Database caching in Django

Tags: python, django, caching

I'm having the following scheme of my project. Every 4 hours I download some data from source, deserialise it and store to database. At the same time, nearly the whole day round some sort of client retrieve this data from my database.

I would like to have no downtimes while updating the database. I've asked similar question before ([Django use two databases for seamless updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652343/django-use-two-databases-for-seamless-updates)), but now I'm learned about caching and think that two databases is real over-engineering.

What is the best option in Django to create caches for database or/and request (I use `django-rest-framework` for it)?

I suppose that this question is not opinional at all, I'm just searching for the correct way to perform it in Django.

Comment: why don't you spin op a background task using f/e celery, so that you can still process incoming requests?

Comment: This is a bit too broad a question because there are so many right answers... It will also invite opinion-based answers like mine, which is frowned upon here.

About the update, just make all operations within a single transaction and you will be fine. Changes go live when you commit, no downtime or inconsistency.

For cache, I like to set the appropriate expire headers and let the clients and/or intermediate proxies do the caching.

Comment: My update process drops all the database and inserts about 30k items. If I do things like `bulk_update` and `transaction.savepoint()`, will it be fine?